# Categorize the approximate shape of an array of Points in 3D Space

Tags: java, 3d, geometry

I have a set of points in 3d space and I want to be able to categorize the shape that best fits them - cube, sphere, cylinder, planar (flat) etc.

I've looked at supervised/machine learning but since I need first generate a large training data set that's not really suitable.

My dream solution would be a java library with a wonderful magical function something like :

```
public enum ShapeType {
    CUBE,
    SPHERE,
    CYLINDER,
    PLANAR
}

public ShapeType CategorizeShapeFromPoints( 3DPoint[] points )
```

However, any and all help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try to calculate some [moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28mathematics%29) of point cloud to characterize its form. 
Here is example of relevant [paper](http://library.utia.cas.cz/separaty/historie/flusser-rotation%20moment%20invariants%20for%20recognition%20of%20symmetric%20objects.pdf) for 2D case

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on your definition of symmetry. I do quite a lot of this with molecular symmetry. So, as @MBo says, moments are a useful start, but only if the points are uniformly distributed  (if there is a concentration anywhere it will distort the moment analysis. Would a globe with equispaced points and a collection at the pole still be a sphere (because it won't be symmetric).

If you are concerned with whether a point has a partner on the other side then you will have to apply rotations and mirrors. There are well defined symmetry groups for the objects you mention.

It will also matter a lot as to whether you have a surface (e.g. a triangulated mesh or a solid figure). I think until you have a clearer idea no one can give a definite answer.